# WinAPI. How to redraw window which has no background?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Hi I have `WNDCLASSEX` structure which has this data:

```
m_wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
m_wndClass.style = CS_NOCLOSE;
m_wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
m_wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
m_wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
m_wndClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
m_wndClass.hIcon = NULL;
m_wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
m_wndClass.hbrBackground = NULL;
m_wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
m_wndClass.lpszClassName = Checkbox::CHECKBOX_CLASS.c_str(); 
m_wndClass.hIconSm = NULL;
```

I need to have window without background, because I need to draw text on parent window and text may be any color.

Drawing works fine, code for drawing:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC dc = BeginPaint(window, &ps);

    if (!classInfo->m_text.empty())
    {
        HDC wdc = GetDC(window);

        SetBkMode(wdc,TRANSPARENT);
        DrawText(wdc, classInfo->m_text.c_str(), -1, &classInfo->m_textRect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_NOCLIP);
        ReleaseDC(window, wdc); 
    }

    EndPaint(window, &ps);
    break;
}
```

However I have method to change text of label:

```
void Checkbox::SetText(const String& text)
{
    m_text = text;
    SetTextRectSize();   //calculates size of RECT 
    if (m_window != NULL)
        InvalidateRect(m_window, NULL, TRUE);
}
```

After I create window with label I see label, however if I want to change text on it, it doesn't change (I need to manualy resize window and it changes after that). However I hadn't have this problem at the time when I used to have colored background, for example my window class had this:

```
m_wndClass.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(COLOR_3DFACE+1);
```

I want to ask, how to update window which, has no background.

**EDIT:**  I have tried some stuff

`FillRect(dc, &rect, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));`

also tried to change window procedure:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    HDC hdc = (HDC) wp; 
    SetBkMode (hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
}
```

And the result is that I draw new text on previous, after setting `text` into `some longer text` part of label becomes corupted!  [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePt71.png) but after resizing the main window my label becomes readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't set the device context's text foreground color for `DrawText()`, although the default is black.  See [SetTextColor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`SetBkMode(..., TRANSPARENT)` just sets the background color/mode for the `DrawText()` rect, not the entire window.

Comment: I see that of my results. So, I'm asking how to make background transparent and text not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about how to draw the window so it is transparent, but the problem isn't with the drawing at all.

The answer is essentially that everything you have done so far towards making a transparent window is wrong. It **looks** like the window is transparent, but in fact it is not, as you can see from the behaviour you describe when you move and resize the window. That's the classic symptom.

In other words, you haven't made the window transparent, you have just stopped drawing the background. What you see as the background is just whatever happened to be underneath the window when it was first drawn.

You need make a Layered window. To find out how to make transparent windows, go here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Do you want Text/Check/Label be transparent on parent form?

You can Add WS_CLIPSIBLINGS and WS_EX_TRANSPARENT..

Use SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT) When WM_PAINT message